# Is methylchloride reaction with water SN1 or SN2

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

I wanted to know if methylchloride reacting with $\ce{H2O}$ would be S<sub>N</sub>1 or S<sub>N</sub>2.

Methyl halide would not react using S<sub>N</sub>1 because methyl carbocation is very unstable but it would also not react using S<sub>N</sub>2 because $\ce{H2O}$ is polar protic.

Please correct me if I am wrong. I think in this problem there would be no reaction. What are your opinions?

Comment: Just because the medium is polar protic, it does not necessitate SN2 not happening.

Comment: Just $\ce{H2O}$ would give you a very slow SN2 reaction. Adding a base eg aq $\ce{KOH}$ would be faster.

Comment: @Aniruddha Deb , So is it correct to say that primary substrate in the presence of polar aprotic solvent, in general, will give a very slow SN2?

Comment: No, the nucleophile is $\ce{OH-}$, whose concentration will increase if you add a base, and since SN2 is bimolecular, the rate will increase. Nothing to do with solvent here.

Comment: @Aniruddha Deb, Thankyou, now I have understood